# How to use the extension method Join()?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I can understand the  string.Join( )

```
  var stringies1 =new [] {"Blood", "is", "Thicker", "Than", "Water" };
  var zoin = string.Join("|", stringies1);
```

How does it differ from extension method Join() ?

**`I mean stringies1.Join(IEnumerable<T Result......)`**

Comment: Sorry I need the diffrence between String.Join( ) and stringies1.Join( )( instance and extension method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension method you're referring to, [Enumerable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx) is for joining collections, which means you place them up side by  side and try to match items against items, producing results. Think of it like matching the phone book with your list of names for a party, to find the phone number for all the names you have on your list.

So, no, the extension method Join can not be used to place them one array after each other and combine them to one long array.

There is an alternative however, you can use the extension method [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) in the same class.

This method does not operate on/with only arrays, but on all collection types that implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and will thus also produce another `IEnumerable<T>` as its result. This result you can then convert to an array using [Enumerable.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx).

Thus, you would use the following code:

```
var stringies1 = new [] {"Blood", "is", "Thicker", "Than", "Water" };
var stringies2 = new [] { "and", "so", "is", "wine" };

var stringies3 = stringies1.Concat(stringies2).ToArray();
// stringies3 now contains "Blood", "is", ... and "and", "so", "is", ...
```

This assumes you're using .NET 3.5 and have the following in the using-list at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If, on the other hand, you (or someone else finding this answer) are not using .NET 3.5, you need some manual code. Here's a simple generic method (assumes .NET 2.0) that can help you:

```
public static T[] Concat<T>(T[] firstSource, T[] secondSource,
    params T[] restOfSources)
{
    // omitted validation of non-null arguments, etc.

    Int32 totalLength = firstSource.Length + secondSource.Length;
    foreach (T[] source in restOfSources)
        totalLength += source.Length;

    T[] result = new T[totalLength];
    Int32 currentIndex = 0;

    Array.Copy(firstSource, 0, result, currentIndex, firstSource.Length);
    currentIndex += firstSource.Length;

    Array.Copy(secondSource, 0, result, currentIndex, secondSource.Length);
    currentIndex += secondSource.Length;

    foreach (T[] source in restOfSources)
    {
        Array.Copy(source, 0, result, currentIndex, source.Length);
        currentIndex += source.Length;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
var stringies1 = ...
var stringies2 = ...

var stringies3 = YourClass.Concat(stringies1, stringies2);
```

Comment: Please explain me the use of extension method Join()

Comment: Please accept my applogies for confusing you.I exactly want the answer what Fredrik explained.I am amazing you immediate response and interest in explaining the things to others.

Comment: In any case, it's Concat you're after for concatenating two arrays/collections, and ToArray to produce an array out of the results.

Comment: Ofcourse what you said is correct.Isn't  it possible to clear(delete) all hit out entries from your post ?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by the extension method, you are referring to the `Enumerable.Join` method? The `string.Join` an IEnumerable.Join are two rather different methods:

- `string.Join` will take an array of strings, join them together using some separator, and return the resulting string.
- [`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) will act on two collections much in the same way as a JOIN operation in SQL does

Comment: Yes this is want i need.Thanks buddy.

Comment: I confused Lasse ,otherwise he would have given me the exact things what i want.So with your permission ,i will vote his entry as expected answer.

Comment: @udana: You just go ahead and do that. No problem :o)

Answer (score -1):

Same function different approach for readability, and less code when appropriate.

Comment: But they're not the same function. One works with strings and the other works with two collections.